# Adapter for list view

Tags: android

please guide me with this program. Why do we need to use an array adapter to show the list? What is this "adapter", and can we display things directly in the ListView, without an adapter? Like, can we set setListAdapter(names) instead of setListAdapter(adapter);? Thanks.
Here is the code:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class Episode7 extends ListActivity {


    String[] names = {
        "Elliot","Geoffrey","Samuel","Harvey","Ian","Nina","Jessica",
        "John","Kathleen","Keith","Laura","Lloyd"
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create an ArrayAdapter that will contain all list items
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

        /* Assign the name array to that adapter and 
           also choose a simple layout for the list items */ 
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                names);

        // Assign the adapter to this ListActivity
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the android API reference,

> An Adapter object acts as a bridge between an AdapterView and the underlying data for that view. The Adapter provides access to the data items. The Adapter is also responsible for making a View for each item in the data set.

It basically a set of interfaces that determine how the data will be handled by the list. You can use different pre-made adapter classes in your lists or create your own if you want to present custom data.

Take a look at this page in the Dev Guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/binding.html

Lars Vogel has a nice tutorial also: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 2):

The Adapter acts as both a container for the information you want to display, and allows you to change how it is displayed by over-riding the getView() method of the adapter. Normally, by default, the adapter will call the toString() method of the Object used to create the Adapter and set the text in the TextView that is referenced in the layout provided by android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1... but by over-riding the adapter's getView(), you can have a more complicated layout display for the list.

To answer the initial question... you must use an adapter with a ListView.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it and it works for me:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ListViewDemo extends Activity {

// --------- Create your string array, adapter and ListView
String[] items = {"Cars", "Money","Vacation","Electronics",
        "Shoes","Jewelry", "Buku bucks","Cash","Ham","Swag","Straight      Cash","Homies","Roll Dawgs","Nate Dogg","Wiz Khalifa","Mac Miller","Chitty Bang",
        "Sam Adams","Technine","Kanye West","Rims","Escalade","Spreewells","Chrome Rims","24's",
        "Lebron James","Dwayne Wade","Andre Iguodala","Allen Iverson","Jodi Meeks",
        "Levoy Allen","Mo Williams","Eric Snow","Alien Iverson","Laptop","Phone","Tablet"};

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ListView cashList;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    cashList = new ListView(this);
    // create the array adapter<String>(context, layout, array)
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    // add the adapter to the list
    cashList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // set the list as the content view
    setContentView(cashList);


}



}
```